# When are environment variables loaded by java virtual machine for a program

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have a java program that I am writing that needs to use environment variables to find a policy file on start up of certain classes.

However, the environment variable value will be **conditional** based on what the purpose is of the class that is being entered by the program. For that reason then I would like to basically load the environment variables on the fly.

However, I am not sure if this is possible since I am not too positive when the environment variables that will be used by a java program's virtual machine are loaded, or if after the environment variables are loaded, they can be changed.

When are the environment variables for a system loaded by a java virtual machine, and can those environment variables set in the virtual machine for the program ever be changed?

Comment: Can you just load them normally and pass whatever subset you need depending on the the path the execution takes?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas I am not sure. The conditional one I need to use is a QOS policy file location for RTI dds. So I am starting multiple writers from the DDS system and one writer needs a keep all history QOS and another needs a keep some history QOS

Comment: Can you not decide this as part of a bash script (or similar) so that when you launch the JVM the decision has already been made, and you pass in the details you need on the command line?

Comment: @Brad that is a possibility I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach "if" you really need to set environment variables, is to code this logic in a wrapper script before launching the JVM (e.g. *.sh, *.cmd)

You can then set the environment variables accordingly using `export` (linux) or `set` windows, etc.